# How do I specify a tsconfig.json for assetic's TypeScript filter?

Tags: symfony, typescript, assetic

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and the assetic bundle. I have this in my config.yml:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        typescript: 
            bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc"
            apply_to: "\\.ts$"
```

When I try to compile my TypeScript files, I get this error:

```
Output:
../../../../private/var/folders/94/45yn02792ksfglm12pjxxlp00000gn/T/assetic_typescript_in59bccf08e6357/my-form.ts.ts(6,1): error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'out' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.
../../../../private/var/folders/94/45yn02792ksfglm12pjxxlp00000gn/T/assetic_typescript_in59bccf08e6357/my-form.ts.ts(6,22): error TS2307: Cannot find module './my-obj.model'.
```

This occurs after I use an import statements like `import { Obj } from './my-obj.model';`. If I don't use import statements, ts compilation works fine.

How do I add give assetic's TypeScript filter either a `--module system` parameter or a `tsconfig.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'out' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.

Extra options for `tsc` command through `AsseticBundle` is not possible at the moment.

> error TS2307: Cannot find module './model'.

and here `AsseticBundle` save each individual `ts` file into a tmp dir/file to compile it, so it doesn't support this feature either.

The good news is that you can override the behavior of the `assetic.filter.typescript` service to fix it. Let's add this class to the application:

```
namespace AppBundle\Assetic\Filter;

use Assetic\Asset\AssetInterface;
use Assetic\Exception\FilterException;
use Assetic\Util\FilesystemUtils;

class TypeScriptFilter extends \Assetic\Filter\TypeScriptFilter
{
    private $tscBin;
    private $nodeBin;

    public function __construct($tscBin = '/usr/bin/tsc', $nodeBin = null)
    {
        $this->tscBin = $tscBin;
        $this->nodeBin = $nodeBin;
    }

    public function filterLoad(AssetInterface $asset)
    {
        $pb = $this->createProcessBuilder($this->nodeBin
            ? array($this->nodeBin, $this->tscBin)
            : array($this->tscBin));

        // using source path to compile and allow "imports".
        $inputPath = $asset->getSourceRoot().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$asset->getSourcePath();
        $outputPath = FilesystemUtils::createTemporaryFile('typescript_out');

        $pb
            ->add($inputPath)
            // passing the required options here
            ->add('--module')->add('system')
            ->add('--out')
            ->add($outputPath)
        ;

        $proc = $pb->getProcess();
        $code = $proc->run();

        if (0 !== $code) {
            if (file_exists($outputPath)) {
                unlink($outputPath);
            }
            throw FilterException::fromProcess($proc)->setInput($asset->getContent());
        }

        if (!file_exists($outputPath)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Error creating output file.');
        }

        $compiledJs = file_get_contents($outputPath);
        unlink($outputPath);

        $asset->setContent($compiledJs);
    }
}
```

Then, change the value of the parameter class to override the original service:

```
# app/config/services.yml
parameters:
    assetic.filter.typescript.class: 'AppBundle\Assetic\Filter\TypeScriptFilter'
```

It worked for me with your `assetic` configuration.

---

In the other hand, the new recommended way to manage assets for Symfony applications: [Webpack Encore](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html) giving you a clean & powerful API for bundling JavaScript modules, pre-processing CSS & JS and compiling and minifying assets, with [support for TypeScript](http://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/typescript.html) loader.

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to tsc bin path, should do the hack  :)

```
assetic:
debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    typescript: 
        bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/../node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --module system"
```